# multinominal logistic regression test using R

Tags: r, logistic-regression

I have two groups of people with different first languages.
I'd like to know if there is a significance in their responses.
There are at least three or four independent factors, and four responses (dependent variables).
Is the script right, or it is only for binary logistic regression?

```
lmer<-lmer(data$response~data$x1+data$x2+data$x3+(1|speaker.info), data=data)
summary(lmer).
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with lmer(), but where exactly do you specify the binomial distribution with the logit link function? Have you looked at glmer()?

Comment: I know of two packages specifically built for fitting a multinomial logistic model: `mlogit` and `mnlogit`. The `lmer` function in the `lme4` package says that it fits "Linear Mixed-Effects Models." Perhaps your model falls into this category, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked at glmer(), mlogit and mnlogit. but I'll try now.

Comment: Hi, I tried mlogit. but i got different values when I add more factors. for example,

Comment: Hi, I tried mlogit. but i got different z values when I add more factors. Anything I did it wrong? Why?
for example,> test <- multinom(response ~ FL, data = fitDC) ( test <- multinom(response ~ FL + Age, data = fitDC))
z <- summary(test)$coefficients/summary(test)$standard.errors